# How do I connect two broken lines along the same direction in matlab

Tags: matlab, tree, branch

I'm trying to select a vessel branch based on user selection.
I've already got the center lines extracted and removed the branch points with a big gap. What I'm thinking to do is if user click on a vessel as a starting point, then it will trace all the way until meeting a branch: if it's a 3-line crossing then both lines are belonging to this branch. if it's a 4-lines crossing, the vertical-ish line belongs to the same branch and the other horizontal-ish lines belongs to another branch, thus not selected.
[image]

How can this be done? this is what the result I imagined..

[image]

Comment: I would try to make an image that contains just those lines, then dilate it and then erode it. See what happens

Comment: If you share some data I can try, else I just can suggest it as a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got decent results using [imerode](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html) and [thinning](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) The values were obtained by trail and error, so this may not be a generic solution. You will also notice that the top of the "tree" disappears. I've only included the last image.

```
%if your image isn't already binary turn it into a logical array
bwim = im2bw(im);

%13 came by trial and error, you can also play with the shape and use something
%besides a disk
thick = imerode(bwim,strel('disk',13));

%the infinite means do untill no changes occur. we use ~thick becasue thin
%works on 1 pixels, not 0's. we then invert the output of bwmorph to get our
%image back to normal (0 foregroun 1 background)
thinned = ~bwmorph(~thick,'thin',inf);

figure(1);imshow(bwim);title('original');
figure(2);imshow(thick);title('after erosion');
figure(3);imshow(thinned);title('after thining');
```

[image]

this looks pretty good, but usually it is better to start with a high quality image rather than start with a bad one and do lots of post processing. I would suggest applying contrast enhancement (like [histogram equalization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/histeq.html) is an easy choice) to the region of interest. You might have to crop out the black background (or if you cant maybe replace it with the average  gray value of the image) before performing your contrast enhancement. After that extract your veins, maybe you won't even need to connect broken pieces at that point.

good luck

Comment: thanks! i didn't solve my original problem but gave me some hint for another one